# Pandas, groupby and counting data in others columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, data-analysis

I have data with four columns, that includes: `Id`, `CreationDate`, `Score` and `ViewCount`.

The `CreationDate` has a next format, for example: 2011-11-30 19:41:14.960.
I need to groupby the years of `CreationDate`, count them, summing `Score` and `ViewCount` also, and to add to additional columns.

I want to use with pandas lib.

Thanks!

Before changing - sample example:

```
     Id   CreationDate              Score   ViewCount
0    1    2011-11-30 19:15:54.070   25      1526
1    2    2011-11-30 19:41:14.960   20      601
2    3    2012-11-30 19:42:45.470   36      1015
3    4    2018-11-30 19:44:55.593   8       1941
4    5    2011-11-30 19:53:23.387   11      5053
5    6    2018-11-30 20:04:43.757   25      5123
6    7    2011-11-30 20:08:23.267   53      8945
```

After changing - present data like this:

```
     Id   CreationDate              Score   ViewCount
0    1    2011                      109     16125
2    3    2012                      36      1015
3    4    2018                      33      7064
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert column to years by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary for columns with aggregation function, last add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if necessary same order of columns like in original `DataFrame`:

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
df['CreationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreationDate'])

df1 = (df.groupby(df['CreationDate'].dt.year)
         .agg({'Id':'first', 'Score':'sum', 'ViewCount':'sum'})
         .reset_index()
         .reindex(columns=df.columns)
       )

print (df1)
   Id  CreationDate  Score  ViewCount
0   1          2011    109      16125
1   3          2012     36       1015
2   4          2018     33       7064
```